# Quitar espacio entre inputs y celda

Tags: html, css

Necesito quitar el espacio que se produce entre los inputs y y el borde de la celda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table width="100%" border="2" bordercolor="red" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>    
    <th bgcolor="red" width="90">MARCA</th>
    <th bgcolor="red" width="90">MODELO</th>
  </tr>

    <td align="center">
      <select name="MARCA" id="MARCA" required style="text-align-last: center;">
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="MARCA1">MARCA1</option>
        <option value="MARCA2">MARCA2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="MODELO" id="MODELO" style="width:120px; text-align: center;"></td>

<tr>    
  <th bgcolor="red" width="90">TIPO EQUIPO</th>
  <th bgcolor="red" width="90">OBSERVACIONES</th>
</tr>

<td align="center">
  <select name="TIPO_EQUIPO" id="TIPO_EQUIPO" required style="border-color: transparent;">
    <option value="MEDIDOR">MEDIDOR</option>
    <option value="CALIBRADOR">CALIBRADOR</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td align="center"><textarea name="OBSERVACIONES" id="OBSERVACIONES"></textarea></td>
```

Comment: Quita el with="100%" de la table y se lo pones a los input, select, textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, agrega esto a tu archivo CSS:

```
input, select, textarea{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Ahora, con el `<input type="text">` no verías un cambio porque indebidamente usas mucho, los **estilos inline**, me refiero a cuando colocas el atributo `style` en la etiqueta `html`. Yo te sugiero agrupar todos esos estilos en un archivo externo de css, **porque mantener estos estilos a larga es improductivo**, sólo se recomienda (y con sus excepciones) para maquetación dinámica mediante `js` o `php` o algún framework. O en este caso a cada etiqueta de formulario, tendrías que agregar manualmente en el atributo `style` la propiedad `width:100%` o como en el caso que lo hiciste en la etiqueta `<table width="100%" ...`

```css
input, select, textarea{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="2" bordercolor="red" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>    
    <th bgcolor="red" width="90">MARCA</th>
    <th bgcolor="red" width="90">MODELO</th>
  </tr>

    <td align="center">
      <select name="MARCA" id="MARCA" required style="text-align-last: center;">
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="MARCA1">MARCA1</option>
        <option value="MARCA2">MARCA2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="MODELO" id="MODELO" style="text-align: center;"></td>

<tr>    
  <th bgcolor="red" width="90">TIPO EQUIPO</th>
  <th bgcolor="red" width="90">OBSERVACIONES</th>
</tr>

<td align="center">
  <select name="TIPO_EQUIPO" id="TIPO_EQUIPO" required style="border-color: transparent;">
    <option value="MEDIDOR">MEDIDOR</option>
    <option value="CALIBRADOR">CALIBRADOR</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td align="center"><textarea name="OBSERVACIONES" id="OBSERVACIONES"></textarea></td>
```

**Pd:** También, como sugieren en otra respuesta, podrías quitar al `table` la propiedad `width: 100%`, pero esto solo hará que la tabla no sea responsive, cosa que no se si en tu diseño sea conveniente.

### Sugerencias (no obligatorias)

Otra cosa que te sugiero es estudiar más sobre `html y css`, veo que usas muchos las etiquetas th, obviando que estas deberían usarse sólo dentro de la etiqueta `thead` y este solo debería de estar una sola vez en toda la tabla, por lo que te recomiendo usar una clase en las filas para realizar estos estilos en las celdas que usarás como titulares. Algo así:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.tabla, input, textarea, select{
  width: 100%;
}

.tabla{ 
  border: solid 2px red; 
  margin: auto; /*reemplazando align="center"*/
  text-align: center; /*Para que los textos siempre esten centrados*/
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.celda-titulo td{
  background-color:red; 
  width: 90px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


#tipo_equipo{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabla">
  <tr class="celda-titulo">    
    <td>MARCA</td>
    <td>MODELO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="marca" id="marca" required>
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="MARCA1">MARCA1</option>
        <option value="MARCA2">MARCA2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="MODELO" id="MODELO"></td>

<tr class="celda-titulo">    
  <td>TIPO EQUIPO</td>
  <td>OBSERVACIONES</td>
</tr>

<td align="center">
  <select name="tipo_equipo" id="tipo_equipo" required>
    <option value="MEDIDOR">MEDIDOR</option>
    <option value="CALIBRADOR">CALIBRADOR</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <textarea name="OBSERVACIONES" id="OBSERVACIONES">
  </textarea>
</td>
```

Si te das cuenta, si usas un modelo de caja tradicional el 100% del ancho, presentará problemas en ciertas partes de desbordamiento, sugiero como te puse en la anterior demo, que agregues la propiedad: `box-sizing: border-box;` ya sea en la tabla y todos sus elementos anidados, usando el selector `table, table *` o simplemente con el selector universal, que se considera hoy una mejor práctica: `*{box-sizing: border-box}`. Si tienes alguna otra duda, escribeme en los comentarios. Éxitos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que le estas especificando a la tabla un width (ancho) del 100%
Al quitárselo, queda como quieres

```
    <table border="2" bordercolor="red" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>    
    <th bgcolor="red" width="90">MARCA</th>
    <th bgcolor="red" width="90">MODELO</th>
  </tr>

    <td align="center">
      <select name="MARCA" id="MARCA" required style="text-align-last: center;">
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="MARCA1">MARCA1</option>
        <option value="MARCA2">MARCA2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="MODELO" id="MODELO" style="width:120px; text-align: center;"></td>

<tr>    
  <th bgcolor="red" width="90">TIPO EQUIPO</th>
  <th bgcolor="red" width="90">OBSERVACIONES</th>
</tr>

<td align="center">
  <select name="TIPO_EQUIPO" id="TIPO_EQUIPO" required style="border-color: transparent;">
    <option value="MEDIDOR">MEDIDOR</option>
    <option value="CALIBRADOR">CALIBRADOR</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td align="center"><textarea name="OBSERVACIONES" id="OBSERVACIONES"></textarea></td>
```

Saludos